# Automate NuGet package to include only .js files (not within a csproj or nuspec file)

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I'm trying to automate creating a NuGet package to include .js files within my web project via Visual Studio 2013 when builds are run.  I have done this using the NuGet Package Explorer  but this needs to be automated.

I have used the Nuget package "CreateNewNuGetPackageFromProjectAfterEachBuild" and this seems close but the CreateNuGetPackage.ps1 script restricts to csproj files.  Has anyone done this?  I have searched and read that a powershell solution may be needed.

Does anyone know if this has been solved yet?  At this point I'm ready to learn how to write a powershell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create proper nuspec file with wildchars like below:

```
<files>
  <file src="bin\Debug\*.dll" target="lib" /> 
  <file src="bin\Debug\*.pdb" target="lib" /> 
  <file src="tools\**\*.*" exclude="**\*.log" />
</files>
```

and run just: `nuget.exe pack yournuspec.nuspec`

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the late response.